# жёсткий диск не определяется через usb 3.0 ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb3.0

```
lsusb | grep SATA
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge


dmesg | tail
[ 2093.855817] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 2093.855820] usb 3-1: Product: ASM1153USB3.0TOSATA
[ 2093.855823] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: ASM1153USB3.0TOSATA
[ 2093.855826] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 123456789019
[ 2093.856653] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2093.856904] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
[ 2093.857600] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[ 2094.871152] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASM1153U ASM1153USB3.0TOS 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2094.873056] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2094.875437] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

lspci не определяет, в gparted не определяется.

Определение диска в биосе происходит. SSD открывается. Как мне определить диск как блочное устройство для дальнейшей работы с ним?

**UPD: 1**

Возможно проблема с питанием, есть ли способ проверить выходное напряжение программно?